# Python: How to remove text within round brackets?

Tags: python, regex, text

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
return re.sub('([^)]*)','', myResultStats.text)
```

suggestions?

thanks

Comment: FYI: If you have nested brackets with arbitrary depth, regular expression cannot match them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
return re.sub('\(.*?\)','', myResultStats.text)
```

Parentheses denote capture groups, so you have to escape them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the brackets

```
return re.sub('\([^)]*\)','', myResultStats.text)
```