# How to remove a string from brackets including the brackets with a condition?

Tags: python, regex

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351522/python-how-to-remove-text-within-round-brackets).

I want to remove brackets and the text within, but keep some words. For example I have a list:

```
["Going", "(#)", "(maybe)", "to", "the", "(##)", "(mall)", "market"]
```

I want to keep `(#)` and `(##)`, but remove `(maybe)` and `(mall)`.

Expected output:

```
["Going", "(#)", "to", "the", "(##)", "market"]
```

There can be any number of words with brackets in the list just like *'maybe'* and *'mall'*.

Brackets with `#` can have maximum of 3 hash.

Comment: What did _you_ try? Since you've been introduced to the concept of regular expressions in that question, did you try to go through any tutorials? Did you try to understand how that regex works? Did you make any attempt at this problem?

Comment: Yes I have, I did put the input in regexr.com so I don't have to run the python code again and again, I have gone through some tutorials but I immediately got confused when the expression got a little complex, instead of writing my completely wrong and mismatched RE I just asked my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension to filter the original list using a regular expression:

```
import re

a = ["Going", "(#)", "(maybe)", "to", "the", "(##)", "(mall)", "market"]
b = [word for word in a if re.match(r"[^(]|\(#{1,3}\)", word)]
```

Gives:

```
['Going', '(#)', 'to', 'the', '(##)', 'market']
```

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) matches the pattern ***from the beginning*** of the string. The pattern means:

- `[^(]` - any character ***except*** `(`.
- `|` - or...

  - `\(` - literal parenthesis
  - `#{1,3}` - 1 to 3 repetitions of `#`
  - `\)` - literal parenthesis

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ioc7gu/1)

Answer (score 1):

In a generic way you can parse the list and assess if the word has a pair of brackets. If it does, and if the word inside is not **#, ## or ###**, then you should exclude it from the output. Assuming you have a list of strings:

```
a = ['Going', '(#)', '(maybe)', 'to', 'the', '(##)', '(mall)', 'market']

output = [word for word in a if ('(' not in word and ')' not in word) or word.strip('()') in ['#', '##', '###']]
print(output)
# ['Going', '(#)', 'to', 'the', '(##)', 'market']
```

The `strip` method keeps only the string within the given parameters (in this case `(` and `)`).

You can learn more about list comprehensions here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: Actually your solution is somewhat correct but not what I was trying to ask, my point was the words can be any words occurring in any number of times, that is why I asked the question regarding to `import re`. I have edited my question please do look at it again. thanks